# How to Dynamically create real APEX input items (not just html input)

Tags: oracle, dynamic, oracle-apex

Does anyone know how to dynamically create real Apex items, such as a text input field or a date picker?

We know to do something like so:

```
select 
APEX_ITEM.TEXT (
    p_idx          => 1,
    p_value        => NULL,
    p_attributes   => 'placeholder="placeholder" class="myItem"'
) item from dual
```

What we want is actual items with Apex properties/attributes, similar to when you insert items manually in the builder. Among those for example Template, Label, Value required, Security attributes etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are building any new applications, you should not be using the APEX_ITEM package because it is designated as legacy: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/APEX_ITEM.html#GUID-A111B577-2503-4F4E-962E-192C7D5B5338

Comment: Why do the page items need to be created dynamically? Why not define the items in the Page Designer with Server-Side Condition on whether the item should be rendered or not?

Comment: Thanks for your question. We would like to render forms/apps from metadata, similar to what can be done using a survey builder.

Comment: A survey builder does not need to create the page items dynamically. As I said in my previous comment, you can put the page items on the page and render them if needed using Server-Side Condition. If you need to change the labels on the text fields, you can do that using substitutions with `&P1_LABEL_TEXT.` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, for explaining. We have discussed ideas similar to yours, but consider this. We have for example 10 different input types; text, textarea, number, date, radio, select, checkbox, etc. Then we have for example 10 questions, that could have any input type. Would that not result in 100 items on the page, or have I understood you wrong?

Comment: Note: there's no problem using APEX_ITEM, it's just not really under active development. It's not going away without a replacement. https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4476688/apex-item-officially-deprecated-what-to-use-instead

Comment: Yes, apex_item is fine as such, but it misses all the 'normal' Apex item attributes, as mentioned in the question :-)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so, what approach did you go with?

Comment: We eventually went with making a PL/SQL package that could create APEX pages with standard page items, by using the flow package calls. We reverse engineered this from the code you get when exporting a page inside the APEX builder (UI). We have the user specify what items they want and then run the package to re-build the page. I am not sure I would recommend going that way, but it was fun to explore.